# Move the red "tilmeld dig" button to the right of the image

Tags: html-email, outlook-2010

I've got this responsive email template (that's just a portion of it, more on jsfiddle):

```
<!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://byensejendom.dk/conference/signup/559"
style="height:200px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:140px" stroke="f" fillcolor="#9B4242">
    <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">Tilmeld dig</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->

http://jsfiddle.net/cC5tr/
```

Here are results from Litmus:
https://litmus.com/pub/74df5e9/screenshots

The section that SHOULD format the button right next to the image is enclosed with  tags, however I can't get it right in 2007,2010 and 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the two tables next to each other had both align="left" attribute. I changed the other table's attribute to align="right" and it started working